# socket.io client not receiving messages from server

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to implement a system with two clients one of them sends a message and the other one shall receive it.
The figure below will explain it in a more visual way:

[image: socket.io message communication chart]

So, the client 1 send the message to the server (and this works), the server receives a "push" message and emits a "pop" message that should be picked up by Client 2. 
The problem here is that Client 2 never receives the "pop" message. :(

Here's the code for all of them.

**SERVER.JS**

```
var app = require('express').createServer()
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

app.listen(999);

app.get('/webclient', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/web.html');
});

app.get('/mobile', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/mobile.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
//      socket.emit('pop', { hello: 'world' });
    socket.on('push', function (data) {
        console.log('push received, emitting a pop');
        socket.emit('pop', { hello: 'world' });
    });
});
```

**CLIENT 1 ( aka mobile.html )**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Mobile
        </title>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.4.5/mootools-yui-compressed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
          var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:999');
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" name="act" id="push" value="message" />
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            window.addEvent('domready', function() {
                $('push').addEvent('click', function() { 
                    socket.emit('push', { hello: 'world' });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CLIENT 2 (aka web.html)**

```
<script src  = "/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:999');
  socket.on('pop', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
</script>
```

I just cannot understand the reason why Client 2 does not receive the "pop" message, 
I'm quite new to socket.io and node.js in general so some mechanics to me are still a bit obscure, so I apologize in advance for my noobness. :)

cheers

-k-

Comment: I'm not experienced with socket.io, but if I'm not mistaken `socket` will refer to the same socket you received the message from. Could you try `io.sockets.emit` instead?

Comment: works like a charm! if you wanna make an answer I can mark it as correct and get you a +1 :)

Comment: +1 for an interesting question well asked and formatted

Comment: thanks, I'm glad it was helpful to somebody else :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The function passed to `.on` is called for each socket to do the initialization (binding events etc), and `socket` refers to that current socket. This will be client 1 when you receive a `push` message, because the handler function is bound to the `push` event of that `socket` - you bound that function when client 1 connected (where `socket` refers to client 1).

`io.sockets` refers to all sockets connected, so including client 2 in your case.

Comment: i dont get it, what worked like a charm? what's the edit?

Comment: This was just an explanation to remove the confusion between **socket** and **io.sockets**.

Answer (score 19):

Another aspect which you could take into consideration is the use of :

`socket.broadcast.emit('push', { hello: 'world' });`

Which would essentially send the message to all the connected clients except the one that originated the message. Removing the task of filtering clients/reducing unnecessary traffic to the originating socket.

[Socket.IO on GitHub](https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io) - Under broadcasting.

Comment: that's also interesting, but as now I need to keep track of my clients and I need to deliver the message to a determined client, so I've managed anther solution, but this could come in handy for the future, thanks!!

Comment: You, sir, deserve an upvote. It worked for me greately after 8 hours of trying with no results!!